# How to set a WinForm text property using string values in a private static void function

Tags: c#, winforms, static

I am trying to incorporate some third party C# example code into my program. The third party code is part of a WinForms NET 4.6.2 application that scans devices on a COM port.

In my case, I want to insert a line (or two) of code within a method `private static void PortStatusCallback()`. My added code is designed to populate some text boxes on my Form1 with some of the variable values in `PortStatusCallback()`. The method in full is below; my proposed addition is the single line `myPortname.Text = portname;`. This addition returns the error message *An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Form1.myPortname'*

Please can anyone suggest a way to access fields from a static method? I am new to C# programming so I would be grateful if you could write out the code for me. Thank you.

```
private DLL.PortStatusCallbackFuncPtr _PortStatusInstance = new DLL.PortStatusCallbackFuncPtr(PortStatusCallback);  // Allocated to prevent garbage collection

private static void PortStatusCallback([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] String portname, DLL.PortStatusTypes status, byte curScanAdr, byte maxScanAdr, byte foundType)
        {
            string statusMsg = "\r\nPortInfo Callback: " + portname + " status:" + status.ToString() + " curScanAdr:" + curScanAdr.ToString() + " maxScanAdr:" + maxScanAdr.ToString() + " foundType:" + foundType.ToString("X2");

            myPortname.Text = portname; // this line is added by me and throws up a CS0120 error.

            MyStatusBox.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate () { MyStatusBox.AppendText(statusMsg); });

            Console.Write(statusMsg);
        }
```

Comment: Why is it a static method?

Comment: Very important reference: **[static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static)**

Comment: You can think of a static member (a field, property, method, etc) as _belonging to the class_ and not _belonging to a specific instance of the class_. In your case, you have a class-level (`static`) method (`PortStatusCallback`) trying to set `myPortname.Text`. I'm assuming that `myPortname` is a property on your form, which is an instance of your Form class `Form1`. You can't do that. Probably the solution is to make the callback function specific to a particular form. We really can't tell you how to do that, it's your program (most of which we can't see)

Comment: Thanks for the replies. @Flydog57 you are correct `myPortname` is a property on my form. Unfortunately, I don't know what you mean by "the solution is to make the callback function specific to a particular form". `PortStatusCallback()` is a method in the `public partial class Form1 : Form` if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer assumes that your `Form1` class represents the main form for your application; that one instance of the class is created in Program.cs, that no other instances are ever created, and when you close the form, the app goes away (i.e., a typical WinForms app).

Create a semi-private property:

```
public static Form1 CurrentForm { get; private set; }
```

In the Form1 constructor (or in the `Load` handler), do the following:

```
CurrentForm = this;
```

Now, the expression `Form1.CurrentForm` will resolve to your main form (from anywhere in your application).

Finally change the line that is erroring on you to:

```
CurrentForm.myPortname.Text = portname;
```

Comment: Thank you @Flydog, that's superb! I had to change the semi private property as follows:


```    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private static Form1 CurrentForm { get; set; } // private set; gives CS0273 error

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            CurrentForm = this; //
        }
 
 //...other stuff

    }```

The code appears to work with `set` instead of `private set`. But will this cause problems elsewhere?

Thank you again for going to the trouble of solving my problem!

Comment: Nope, shouldn't cause an issues. By the way: If you want a word/phrase to show up like `code` enclose it in single backticks. Triple backticks are for blocks of vode

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [static modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) like this:

```
private static DLL.PortStatusCallbackFuncPtr _PortStatusInstance = new DLL.PortStatusCallbackFuncPtr(PortStatusCallback);  // Allocated to prevent garbage collection
```